# Partial derivatives confusion in the equation $PV=nrT$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question is to exactly: "If the variables $P,V$ and $T$ are related by the equation $PV=nRT$ where $n$ and $R$ are constant, simplify the expression"
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}
$$
The first step of the solution confuses me. The solution solves explicitly for $V$ and solves
$$
V=\frac{nrT}{P}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial V}{\partial T}=\frac{nr}{P}
$$
Treating $P$ as constant with respect to $T$, which it isn't, since 
$$
P=\frac{nrT}{V}
$$
Where is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: It would help if you gave more context. If you provide clear definitions of each of the functions $V$, $T$ and $P$ that might also help clear up your confusion.

Comment: That's what a partial derivative *is* -- the derivative with respect to one variable while holding the others constant.

Comment: @Bye_World holding other independent variables, but not variables which depend on the independent variables! I guess maybe the problem is that if I were to plug the identity for $P$ I have above, it would be redundant

Comment: @smcc There isn't much more, but I will copy verbatim

Comment: You need to decide what is a function of what.  At any rate,
$\partial P / \partial T$ and $\partial T / \partial P$ look mutually reciprocal.

Comment: @avs right, so would I be correct in saying that he solution has decided to solve explicitly for $V$ and once this is decided, you have taken all other variables to be independent?

Comment: @avs: Just out of a concern for symmetry, maybe the last partial derivative is $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$.

Comment: @BrianTung gosh youre right editing

Comment: If we are allowing pressure to change with respect to temperature, then there should be no change in the volume as the pressure has changed to account for the increase in kinetic energy. Vice-versa, if we are allowing volume to change with respect to temperature, then the pressure should not be changing.

Comment: You are missing all the fun. In fact, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ is **always** the same, regardless of the particular equation of state, ideal gas or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial derivative of

$$V(n,r,T,P)=\frac{nrT}{P}$$

with respect to $T$ is just

$$\frac{\partial V(n,r,T,P)}{\partial T}= V_T(n,r,T,P)=\frac{nr}{P}.$$

Just treat $n$, $r$ and $P$ as constants, i.e. think of it is a function, $v$ of one variable $v(T)=V(n,r,T,P)$.

Comment: It's the ideal gas law! $r$ is *literally* a constant.

Comment: Okay, pardon me if I do not know the ideal gas law! (It does not matter anyway.)

Comment: No problem hahaha :)

Comment: @smcc so in step 1, you have made the choice that $V$ is a function of all other variables, and cannot change this for the rest of the problem, yes?

Comment: If you are thinking of $V$ as the endogenous variable and the other variables as exogenous, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the present context the 'understanding' is that when taking derivatives of $V$ the variables are the two others, i.e. for $\partial V/\partial T$ the variables are $P$ and $T$ (and $P$ is held constant). Similarly for the other partial derivatives. From $V=nrT/P$, $T=PV/nr$ and $P=nrT/V$ we therefore get:
$$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \frac{\partial T}{\partial P} \frac{\partial P}{\partial V} 
= \frac{nr}{P} \times \frac{V}{nr} \times \frac{-nrT}{V^2} = \frac{-nrT}{PV} = -1$$
which I presume is the answer given in the text ?
Often the notation makes more explicit which variables are fixed. The fact that you get -1  is by the way a general result from differential geometry and independent of the specific form of the law for the ideal gas.